# Angular: always get popup blocker on create new tab after async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I have following scenario:

- User tries to login with wrong password
- on failure I ask him if he wants to reset password
- if user click 'OK' (pure `confirm dialog`) , I'll open new tab with some URL.

My problem is: **I always get  popup blocker** because I generate `window` only after error callback. Here is relevant code `login` method:

```
 $scope.login = function () {

            $auth.login({
                email: $scope.fields.email,
                password: $scope.fields.password
            })
                .then(function () {

                        // ... login success
                })
                .catch(function () {

                  // login failed (my case)

                 if (confirm('ERROR: Invalid password, forgot Password? Click \'OK\' if you want to reset it')){

                   var url_ = 'http://meeter.me/#/forgot-pass/snaggs@gmail.com';

                    var myPopup = window.open ('',  '_blank');


                    myPopup.location = url_;
                    if (myPopup && myPopup.focus) {
                      myPopup.focus();
                    }       
                 }// if


                });

        };
```

If I move `var myPopup = window.open ('',  '_blank');` to next line under `$scope.login = function ()` it will work but it will open new empty tab.

I want to open new tab only when get error on login

*I use [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)*

Please help,

---

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qX69kUPcKTT2i7N3pNCD?p=preview)

In demo i use single `$timeout` to simulate async call

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is going to be possible to open a new window using window.open if it is invoked asynchronously. Without user invocation, the call stack is always going to identify that window.open is triggered asynchly and going to block it. Maybe an option to show a new button if login is failed and let that button open up a new window?

http://plnkr.co/edit/QGfnxH484OdTvaaOvMaE?p=preview

```
<button ng-click="init();">press  me</button><br />
<span ng-show="resetPwd" >
Login Failed!! <button ng-click="reset()">Reset Password</button>
</span>

$scope.init = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.resetPwd = true;
  }, 2000);
}
```